# Deleting records from External Table in Siebel takes long time

Tags: siebel

I created a Business Service in Siebel to delete records from an External Table based on a condition. The searchspec takes only milli seconds to execute. But the function DeleteRecord() takes 190 seconds to delete each record from the table. As it takes around 190 seconds to delete each record, my application got hung.

Is there any limitations for External Table?
What could be the cause of the issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing implementation details it will be difficult to figure out the cause.

There is overhead when using EBC which is spread over Siebel, Network and Database. To minimize overhead cost and improve performance try shifting logic to Database side using

> Stored Procedure

and by passing the SearchSpec as Parameter to Stored Procedure. This will surely save you from hung state.